# Exception KeyError: KeyError(139697538152192,) on using threading module with atexit handler

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to add a atexit handler to my code. But I find that if I have imported threading module, it gives me an KeyError exception. Is this a bug in python threading module?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import threading

# Register a signal handler to exit gracefully
def exit_gracefully():
    print 'Exiting ...'
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)

import atexit
atexit.register(exit_gracefully)
```

On running the above script, I get

```
Exiting ...
Exception KeyError: KeyError(139697538152192,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Comment: You are not using threading module. Have you tried removing it? Does the error stay?

Comment: Also, can you try the same code piece in python shell >>> just the import threading. Does it give the same error?

Comment: Ofcourse I know I am not using threading module. But in need to use threading module, and thats causing trouble. This script is just a stripped down version of the actual script that shows the problem

Comment: The issue is seen on interactive shell too on exiting it by pressing Ctrl+D

Comment: Couldn't find anybody else on the internet with the same problem as me. I was running into the same issue! I think there is a bug with the atexit module. I'm not importing threading in my code and still getting the same key error above.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I get this issue only when threading module was loaded.
I managed to solve it by not invoking sys.exit within exit handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import threading

# Register a signal handler to exit gracefully
def exit_gracefully():
    print 'Exiting ...'

import atexit
atexit.register(exit_gracefully)
```